# Changes in the mean absolute difference (relating to the Gini coefficient)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, economics

Consider the expression for one half of the mean absolute difference divided  by the mean $\mu$, i.e., $\frac{1}{2\mu{n^2}}\Sigma^n_{i=1} \Sigma^n_{j=1} |y_i-y_j|$ (the Gini coefficient). How does it change if we add one more entry $y_{n+1}$ to the array $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$ that we are considering? Can we say when it is going to increase, decrease or stay constant, depending on $y_{n+1}$? Or, in other words, can you solve the following for $y_{n+1}$?

$\frac{1}{2\mu{n^2}}$ $\Sigma^n_{i=1} \Sigma^n_{j=1} |y_i-y_j| = \frac{1}{2\mu^\prime{(n+1)^2}}$ $\Sigma^{n+1}_{i=1} \Sigma^{n+1}_{j=1} |y_i-y_j| $,

where $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma^n_{i=1}y_i$ and $\mu^\prime=\frac{1}{n+1}\Sigma^{n+1}_{i=1}y_i$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for an expression for the $y_{n+1}$ which leaves the Gini coefficient unchanged?

Comment: Yes. And ideally I would like to see some intuitive gloss on the result. E.g., something like "the Gini is unchanged if $y_{n+1}$ is at the median of the distribution {$y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_n$}".

Comment: OK - think about this.  If your original data is $\{2,2,2,2,2,6,10,10,10,10,10\}$ then you have a mean and median of $6$.  I think on your definition the Gini coefficient is about $0.3306$.  If you want the Gini coefficient to stay constant then you need an additional observation of about $4.868552$ or about $12.486486$; if instead the addition observation is between these (including, for example, the original median of $6$) then the Gini coefficient will reduce.  I do not know if the $486$s are a coincidence

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the general rule will be (if there is going to be one at all)?

Comment: I do not know a general rule, but I would expect there to be three regions: introduce $y_{n+1}$ close to zero and the Gini coefficient should rise; introduce a moderate to fairly high $y_{n+1}$ and the Gini coefficient should fall; introduce an extremely high $y_{n+1}$ and the Gini coefficient should rise. And with continuity there should be two values of  $y_{n+1}$ where it does not change